# NetSuite Saved Search that display checkbox column

Tags: netsuite

I'm a bit new to Oracle NetSuite. I created a saved search for Work Order and I want to add column/custom field that will displays as a CHECKBOX so that this can be selected/unselected for printing. Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

To operate on the results the most straightforward way to do that would be with a Suitelet that displays a list. You can add a checkbox to the results and then process the checked items when the List is posted back.

Comment: can you send a sample netsuite script for this if possible. thanks

Comment: What I have is pretty application specific. The Netsuite help is fairly good on this topic.